# Automate coding of a field in a dataset by searching a different text field in it

Tags: excel, vba, loops, paste

I'm a novice Excel macro writer and have produced the following code via searching/using forum posts on similar things. What I'm trying to do is this: I have a big data set, with a particular field in it that contains text strings. It also has a new field I've added for profit centre, which is currently blank. I then have a separate master data table with two fields - one for identifiable terms that sometimes appear in the text field of the data set, and the second for the profit centre that should be associated with that term if it appears in the text field. I want to use the second table to populate as many profit centres in the data set as possible, by looping a text search. I guess this requires the loop to take the first data set row, loop through all the master data rows, then go to the second data set row, loop through all the master data rows again, and so on (or vice versa).

```
    Sub mySearch()

    Dim myData As Worksheet
    Dim myRules As Worksheet
    Dim myDataRow As Long
    Dim myRuleRow As Long
    Dim myLastDataRow As Long
    Dim myLastRuleRow As Long
    Dim myFind As String
    Dim myRule As String
    Dim Pos As Long

'   Specify name of Data sheet
    Set myData = Sheets("Data")

'   Specify name of Sheet with list of rules
    Set myRules = Sheets("Rules")

'   Assuming lists of data & rules start in column A on row 2, find last entries in lists
    myLastDataRow = myData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    myLastRuleRow = myRules.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Loop through both lists - data & identification items

    For myDataRow = 2 To myLastDataRow

    For myRuleRow = 2 To myLastRuleRow
'       Get find and copy values (from columns A and B)
        myFind = myRules.Cells(myRuleRow, "A")
        myRule = myRules.Cells(myRuleRow, "B")
        myRules.Cells(myRuleRow, "B").Copy
'       Start at top of data sheet and do finding
        myData.Activate
'       Ignore errors that result from finding no matches
        On Error Resume Next
'       Do all pasting on column W of data sheet
        Pos = InStr(Range(myDataRow, "C"), "MyFind")
        If Pos > 0 Then Range(myDataRow, "W").Select.Paste
'       Reset error checking
        On Error GoTo 0

    Next myRuleRow

    Next myDataRow

'   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Searches complete!"

End Sub
```

The code is running to completion but is not populating the profit centre field in the data set. I think it's the pasting of the relevant profit centre that I haven't got right. Can anyone help me, please? Thanks, Lynne

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different approach, using a dictionary to store the profit center keys (the "identifiable terms") and their corresponding profit center ID taken from the master list of profit centers, and using the `range.Find` method to identify cells in your main data that contain these terms.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindProfitCentres()
    '// This approach uses a dictionary of profit centres to search for matching
    '// key value within a single column of text.

    '// The profit center key value text, to be matched, and their corresponding
    '// profit center IDs are in a 2-column table named "ProfitCenterLookup"

    '// The input data to be searched is in a two-column area named InputData -
    '// the first column being the text to be searched for matches against
    '// profit center keys, and the second column to be the place that the resulting
    '// profit center code, if found, is to be placed.


    '// PROFIT CENTER DICTIONARY
    '// First build a dictionary of string keys that identify profit centers
    '// NOTE: You must add a reference to Scripting Runtime in the Tools>References section
    '// of the VB dev window

    Dim oPCDict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    '// Get the profit center data table
    Dim rPCTable As Range
    Set rPCTable = Me.Range("ProfitCenterLookup")

    '// Save profit center data in the dictionary
    Dim ix As Integer
    For ix = 1 To rPCTable.Rows.Count
        With rPCTable.Rows(ix)
            If Len(.Cells(1, 1)) <> 0 Then
                '// Check for duplicate keys - these are ignored
                If Not oPCDict.Exists(.Cells(1, 1)) Then
                    oPCDict.Add .Cells(1, 1).Value, .Cells(1, 2).Value
                End If
            End If

        End With

    Next ix


    '// Get the list of the profit center keys from the dictionary
    '// We will use this list to do the search
    Dim aPCKeys() As Variant
    aPCKeys = oPCDict.Keys

    '// Variables
    Dim oResult As Range            'Result of .Find operation
    Dim sPrCenter As Variant        'Profit center code when found
    Dim rInputData As Range         '2-column area of input data
    Dim rSearchCol As Range         'Column 1 of this area - the text to be searched
    Dim rPrCtrCol As Range          'Column 2 of this area - where the pr center will be updated
    Dim sKey As String              'Profit center key to be found in the search data

    '// Get the input data, the search column and the output profit center column
    Set rInputData = Me.Range("InputData")
    Set rSearchCol = rInputData.Columns(1)
    Set rPrCtrCol = rInputData.Columns(2)

    '// Clear previously found profit centers from the output column
    rPrCtrCol.ClearContents

    '// Loop through each of the keys
    For ix = 0 To UBound(aPCKeys)

        '// Get the profit center key to be found
        sKey = aPCKeys(ix)

        '// Search for the first occurrence, if any, of the key in the search column
        Set oResult = rSearchCol.Find(sKey, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, Searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        '// Check if the key was found and if so update the corresponding profit center
        Do Until (oResult Is Nothing)

            '// We have found a match on a specific key, we use this key
            '// to look up the profit center in the dictionary ...
            sPrCenter = oPCDict.Item(sKey)

            '// ... then place the profit center in the corresponding row of the sheet
            With rPrCtrCol.Cells(oResult.Row, 1)
                If Len(.Value) = 0 Then .Value = sPrCenter
            End With

            '// Go on to find the next match in the search area
            Set oResult = rInputData.Find(sKey, After:=oResult, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, Searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        Loop

        '// Move on to the next profit center key
    Next ix
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - thank you so much for these comprehensive, beautifully explained solutions! First chance I get, I will try both & no doubt learn a lot from both methods. Many thanks again - Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

After posting the previous answer, it occurred to me that there was another approach that might be better for you - using the Excel ability to call a UDF directly from a cell.

The code below is for a UDF that takes two parameters - the first is the text to be searched for a match on an "identifiable term", the second is a reference to the 2-column table of profit centre codes. The UDF returns the profit centre name from Col 2 of the table that corresponds to the first match found in the list of codes in col 1.

I think this approach has advantages: the UDF does not need to be invoked manually to update the column of profit centres - if either the text to be searched or the table of profit centres is updated, the UDF is invoked automatically by Excel; also, you can use the UDF anywhere in your spreadsheet, in any column of any worksheet, and could refer to a single profit centre table or different tables if you need them. This is a lot more flexible than the single UDF relying on specific named ranges. There may be a performance disadvantage, but unless you have a truly huge spreadsheet, this is unlikely to be significant.

```
Option Explicit


Public Function ProfitCenter(rTextToCheck As Range, rPCTable As Range) As Variant
    '// Called as an in-cell formula to return the profit
    '// center code. The first parameter is the
    '// text to be searched, the second is a reference to
    '// table of profit center keys (col 1) and names (col 2)


    '// Get the string to be searched
    Dim sTTC As String
    sTTC = rTextToCheck.Cells(1, 1)

    '// Variables used in the loop
    Dim rPCKeyColumn As Range
    Dim rPCNameColumn As Range
    Dim rPCKey As Range
    Dim sPCKey As String
    Dim irow As Integer: irow = 0

    '// Get references to the keys and the names for profit centres
    Set rPCKeyColumn = rPCTable.Columns(1)
    Set rPCNameColumn = rPCTable.Columns(2)

    '// Find a match on one of the dictionary keys
    '// Run down the list of Profit Center keys
    For Each rPCKey In rPCKeyColumn.Cells
        irow = irow + 1

        '// Get the Profit center key for this row
        sPCKey = rPCKey.Value

        '// Check there is a key
        If Len(sPCKey) > 0 Then

            '// check for a match for the key within the text
            If InStr(sTTC, sPCKey) > 0 Then

                '// If a match is found, return the corresponding profit center name
                ProfitCenter = rPCNameColumn.Cells(irow, 1).Value
                Exit Function

            End If

        End If

    Next

    '// No match was found, so return blank
    '// (or else an error message such as "Not found")
    ProfitCenter = ""

End Function
```

The UDF needs to be placed in a vba Module in the vba project. Then you simply call the UDF in the Profit Centre column of your worksheet like this:

[image: Using ProfitCenter UDF in the worksheet]